# Why odbc_exec always fail?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, odbc

I have this code, the connection always works well, but when executing odbc_exec() its always give me a "error" for all sql commands. I'm using a oracle database and i am connecting with DBA privileges.
In my php page i always get a warning "Warning: odbc_exec()" but no reason is specified.

```
....
$c = odbc_connect(service_name, user, password);
if (!$c)echo 'Failed to connect';
$sql= "SELECT * FROM MEDICOS";
$result = odbc_exec($c,$sql) or die("error");
...
```

Anyone knows what is happening here?
Thank you.

Comment: `MEDICOS` table really exist?

Comment: please paste exact error

Comment: Yeah MEDICOS table exists. It not give me a exact error, only a "Warning: odbc_exec()" but without a reason specified. The odbc_exec always return false. I already try to use oci_connect() and oci_parse() but still stuck on same situation :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I was trying to acess from another user, tables that "SYS" is the owner.
If i do $sql= "SELECT * FROM SYS.MEDICOS" it works well.

Answer (score 0):

When querying with ODBC connections in PHP I have found it is better to use:

```
$query = odbc_prepare($con, $sql);
$result = odbc_execute($query, $_POST);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer :) but still the same problem :/

Comment: Try adding a driver paramater to your ODBC_Connect call.  Something like: ODBC_Connect(Driver={Exact name of ODBC Driver}, service_name, user, password);